# XCode 10 shows no simulators or devices

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I just reinstalled XCode 10 and now navigating to XCode -> XCode -> Open Developer Tool -> Simulator -> Hardware -> Device -> Manage Devices shows no devices or simulators:

[image]

Does anyone know what might cause that behavior, or what I can do to install a simulator version (e.g. iOS 6s)? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this machine had a previous version of XCode installed, and had some legacy simulators that were left over from that earlier XCode installation. Step one was to remove those simulators:

```
xcrun simctl delete unavailable
```

Then I manually created a new simulator:

```
xcrun simctl create duhaime-6s com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-0
```

Those arguments are: `xcrun simctl NAME DEVICE_TYPE RUNTIME`. You make up the simulator name, and can select a device type and runtime from the list of options displayed if you run `xcrun simctl list`. After creating the simulator, you can start it:

```
xcrun simctl boot 4A6368C3-A94C-4D83-8AA3-9E9900ABCC74
```

That GUID / simulator ID will be displayed if you rerun `xcrun simctl list`.